# Mixing bottom app bar and floating action button (FAB)

Tags: android, material-design, user-experience, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I want to use [BottomNavigation](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html) and [FloatingActionButton](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) at the same time in Android and there is nothing like this in [google material components](https://material.io/develop/android/) and also I didn't find any third party library which implements something like this. Attached GIF demonstrate what I want to implement. In fact I want a bottom navigation that one of its tabs has a FAB which placed on the navigation bar and the FAB disappears when another tab is selected.

[See the attached image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8JMs.gif)

Comment: You are looking for bottom app bar. Look here https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html# you will find more..!

Comment: It's not bottom app bar. Bottom app bar concept is something different from what I want to implement. It's more a like a app bar that sticks to bottom and functionality of buttons on it is not to navigate user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find a Material component for the layout in your example since it's counter to the [Material Design Spec](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#).

> Floating Action Button (FAB) represents the primary action of a screen

The example would provide multiple "primary" interactions since its mixed with navigation. I would not recommend using the FAB in the context of a bottom navigation bar. Instead, separate them visually for the user's benefit by moving the FAB up and to the right of the page. Here are the Material Docs for [Extending the FAB](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#extended-fab)

Now you don't *have* to follow the Material Spec **BUT** you shouldn't expect pre-built Material components to ignore it.

Comment: Thank you, I think it does not affect the principles of material design, I just wanted to attach FAB on the bottom bar when one navigation is selected and It will disappear as another navigation is selected. However, thank you for your response, At least Now I'm sure that there is no pre-built component.